# HDBeenDope's use of the word 'LABB' in 'Cayman'

Tags: rap

In the song, 'Cayman' the word LABB is thrown around a lot such as LABB on everything and constantly spelling it out.What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form [thenewnine.com](https://thenewnine.com/hdbeendope-is-making-a-name-for-himself/)

> HDBeenDope’s saying is LABB RAT: Learn and Become Better, Receive and Think. He came up with it around 2013-14. At first, just wanting a “cool” nickname like most rappers around that time, he was just scoping ideas and throwing them out just as fast. Until one day, his friend pointed out to him that he was “just a lab rat,” because he spent most of his time at home making music. He found it offensive at first, taking it personally that someone would insult his work ethic. However, it manifested into more when he saw the bigger picture.